# When worldizing a voice, do you capture ambience tracks?

Tags: worldizing, ambience, track

Question:

If you worldize a few lines of dialogue to make them sound like they are coming from down a stairwell, or down a hallway, and you record with stereo mics or whatever, do you make sure to capture a minute or two of ambience track to use on either side of the dialogue tracks?

My guess would be you would want the scratch track because if it's got a city rumble or florescent lights in the hall or whatever, you'd want that in there to smooth it out.

Or, when you worldize, do you often look to find the quietest space available so you don't have to do this?

I'm curious to what the protocol is.

Thanks!

Comment: That was a great question, I'm glad you thought of that.

Answer (score 4):

Any time I've used this trick I always find the appropriate space to re-record the sound and capture a minute or two of additional room tone. So, yes, record some extra tone while you're there to smooth out editing transitions.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. If you're recording location dialogue you'd always capture room tone if possible, so makes sense to do the same when worldizing.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that when I'm given an omf/aaf, usually there is plenty of ambience in the handles to pullout and "dove-tail" your dialogue.  If not, I try and find some dead space in the dialogue so I can copy and pate it appropriately if the ability to re-record isn't available.